# Missing 50GB on my 100Gb harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, disk-usage, btrfs

I have a 128GB harddrive formatted with the btrfs. However, for some reason I'm missing around half of the disk space. Do any of you have any idea of how to fix it?

See this screenshot for details

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the output of `uname -r`, `mount | grep btrfs`, and `btrfs subvolume list /`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sure - http://i.imgur.com/owIS7fw.png

Comment: Thanks. It would be even better, if you copied the output as text into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `btrfs subvolume list /` shows multiple subvolume snapshots (apparently created by an apt trigger for backup). Those can claim a lot of disk space, if many file blocks have been changed since the creation of the snapshot, and they don't show up in the directory listings (and therefore don't contribute to the disk usage of the listed files).

You can delete old (or all) snapshots with `btrfs subvolume delete [snapshot name]` (see [`man 8 btrfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/btrfs.8.html) for details) if you feel you don't need them anymore. Afterwards a periodically (typically every few seconds) run btrfs kernel service will release the now unused disk space within a minute or so.

If you want do disable or reconfigure that apt trigger, I suggest you create a new question.

On a completely different note, I suggest you add the `ssd` mount flag to your root partition. `/home` has it already.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll test it as soon as I get home. Thank you very much - I think this is the problem

Comment: Just a pedantic note: currently, btrfs [does not support different btrfs-specific mount options for different subvolumes](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_mount_subvolumes_with_different_mount_options.3F), including `ssd`.